# Exclude element from jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am almost positive that this question has been answered before, but the reason that I am asking this question is because I am not sure how to implement the answers into my code without breaking it. I have an accordion menu and it utilizes headers, paragraph tags, divs for the structure of the accordion. Well what I am trying to do is use a div inside of the accordion to display images, but here is the thing: divs are used for the structure of the accordion.

> So, what I am asking is how to have jQuery treat this div as purely
>   content and not part of the structure?

I am pretty sure that the answer is to use `.not()`, but not sure. I only understand the basics when it comes to JavaScript and jQuery. I am really sorry for this guys... I am the type of person that learns by doing, not by reading a book.

```js
var headers = ["H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6"];

$(".accordion").click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

  if ($.inArray(name, headers) > -1) {
    var subItem = $(target).next();

    //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
    var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
    var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div:not(.exclude)").filter(function() {
      if ($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

    //slideToggle target content and adjust bottom border if necessary
    subItem.slideToggle("fast", function() {
      $(".accordion :visible:last").css("border-radius", "0 0 10px 10px");
    });
    $(target).css({
      "border-bottom-right-radius": "0",
      "border-bottom-left-radius": "0"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<aside class="accordion">

  <div class="opened-for-codepen">

    <h2>How do I recruit members?</h2>

    <div class="exclude image_legend">

      <span>Image legend for "How do I recruit members?" section</span>
      <br />
      <br />

      <img src="includes/images/clan/clan-tab.png" height="40px" style="display: inline;" />

      <img src="includes/images/clan/clan-bottom-bar.png" height="40px" style="display: inline\;" />

      <img src="includes/images/clan/clan-recruit.png" height="40px" style="display: inline-block;" />

      <img src="includes/images/clan/clan-tab.png" height="40px" style="display: inline-block;" />

    </div>

    <p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis arcu augue. Donec varius semper interdum. Sed condimentum ipsum enim, a egestas nunc blandit a. Aenean varius dapibus suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Quisque et lectus sapien. Nulla dapibus porta libero ac efficitur. Phasellus condimentum ornare porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nec orci vitae felis mattis suscipit consectetur sit amet urna. Nulla lobortis augue ac commodo condimentum. Maecenas
      ac dui cursus, congue felis quis, varius elit. Curabitur nulla lacus, dignissim ut pellentesque at, posuere sit amet eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nec sapien diam. Nulla
      accumsan viverra tellus sed laoreet. In eleifend nulla libero, vehicula consectetur magna condimentum vitae. Suspendisse non rhoncus justo. Nullam eleifend elit nec neque efficitur, quis fermentum metus pretium. Quisque tellus mauris, molestie in
      ultrices eu, tincidunt ut nibh. Fusce eu volutpat felis. Integer ligula nulla, mattis quis pulvinar pharetra, vehicula nec arcu. Vivamus tincidunt nulla a nisi vehicula lobortis. In hendrerit, neque quis convallis lacinia, nisl ipsum varius lorem,
      nec laoreet nisi odio vitae est. Nulla vitae diam enim. Suspendisse a dignissim magna. Pellentesque convallis maximus mollis. Nullam tellus est, accumsan sit amet facilisis sit amet, semper sed lorem. Mauris laoreet tortor at odio aliquet, ut porta
      lacus rhoncus. Nullam laoreet dolor et velit malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum a erat elementum, hendrerit massa non, ornare enim. Phasellus iaculis diam eros, sit amet dapibus elit finibus id.

    </p>

  </div>

</aside>
```

Edit: The above html is consolidated because there is a lot of content to include all of it, but I provide you with the basic structure that makes the accordion

Comment: Can you show us the markup of you accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to your div (Ex. 'my-class')

Then use not :not() to filter the selection

```
var headers = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6"];

    $(".accordion").click(function(e) {
      var target = e.target,
          name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

      if($.inArray(name,headers) > -1) {
        var subItem = $(target).next();

        //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
        var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
        var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div:not(.my-class)").filter(function() {
          if($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
            return true; 
          }
        });
        $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

        //slideToggle target content and adjust bottom border if necessary
        subItem.slideToggle("fast",function() {
            $(".accordion :visible:last").css("border-radius","0 0 10px 10px");
        });
        $(target).css({"border-bottom-right-radius":"0", "border-bottom-left-radius":"0"});
      }
    });
```

Comment: wrong way round. it would be a lot better to select what you want than filter out what you don't want. Rather add a class to the elements that should slide (or at least their immediate parent).

Comment: After implementing .not()..... The p tag that displays the content, text of the accordion, wont display the text. I tried putting the div inside the p tag and on the bottom neither would show the div, but displays the text. If I put the div on top of the p tag it shows the div, but not the text.